# Is there a wristband-like controller for the wii?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii, wii-u

We've been playing Just Dance and Wii Fit quite a bit lately and I was thinking a small wrist-band or watch type controller would be handy.  The wiimote gets heavy for my 5-year-old and you really just need the motion sensor for these games and maybe "A" and "B" buttons to advance through menus.
Does this exist already?

Comment: Not sure but the "heavy controller" fits the Wii fit very well :D.

Comment: I would suggest that if your 5 year old is finding the unit to be too heavy, you should use this as a time-limit factor.  Children that age should have their screen time limited anyway.  I would not limit them to the draconian limits set by the American Academy of Pediatrics, but the amount of time it takes for them to tire of holding a wiimote is probably a good built-in limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such controller for Wii or Wii-U currently (but nobody knows what Nintendo is cooking up)

This is pretty much a technology/cost barrier. as the motion detection hardware is quite large (although it has been getting smaller if you notice wii-motes now come with motion+ and are the same size as original wii-motes). Hardware that small that stil works effectively in a gaming environment is also probably quite expensive even if it does exist,

If you want to play motion games without the weight of a bulky controller, try investing in the Kinect. Now that the Xbox One is out you could probably find a cheap Xbox 360+Kinect bundle or something.

Answer (score -2):

No. There is only the regular controller.